# Turn-based browser game

Tags: browser-based-games, turn-based

I want to try to build a multiplayer turn-based browser game.

What technologies do you recommend me to use for server side considering I plan to host it on a shared host? Would PHP be fast enough?

Comment: I'm sorry, but we don't allow technology recommendations here because they are too opinion-based. Also, your server requirements can vary by several orders of magnitude depending on how you design your game's network protocol and on how many players you expect, so it's impossible to give you any useful advise in this regard.

Comment: This question is off-topic, see the help center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you expect to have millions of concurrent players, I don't think you have to worry about inherent performance differences of languages or technologies. That is even more true since your game is turn based, meaning you don't need real-time interactions, and it's not that bad if something takes a few milliseconds more here or there. If anything, the shared host environment would be a bigger source of problems than the tech you use, because you can't predict when and if your performance is affected.

The best advice is probably: use a language that you're comfortable with.

Answer (score -2):

You should not let yourself be limited by language, choose the best tool for the job so you don't have to reinvent too many wheels. One possibility is to go with Unity. It can be programmed on either C# or Javascript, the latter should be easy to learn if you already know PHP.

Also, you can find ready made turn based strategy frameworks such as this one:
https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/50282